# register user and htmlspecialchars issue

Tags: php, xss

I'm building registration & login script.

I want to protect my system against XSS attacks.

So I found `htmlspecialchars` function for that.

This is how I use it in `register.php`:

`$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST["username"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

Right now, when I try to register with the username `"> xss<script>alert(1)</script>` alert() function doesn't work, which is nice for me.

But I can't login with the same username because in the database it looks like `&quot;&gt; xss&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt...`

I don't want any innocent user to have difficuluties when he logins somehow because of this issue.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use also same `htmlspecialchars` function when you log user in. (let's say in login.php)

When you do that, user input will become `&quot;&gt; xss&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt...` and it will match to database, and login will be successful.